# How can I subclass a modelform (extend with extra fields from the model)?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model and a form:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_foo = models.CharField(_("Foo"), max_length=50)
    field_bar = models.IntegerField(_("Bar"))

class MyFormOne(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
        fields = ('field_foo', )
        widgets = {'field_foo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'maxlength': 50}),}
```

I would like to have another form `MyFormTwo` which would subclass that form by including also the field `field_bar`. My point is not to have to repeat the widget declaration for `field_foo` in the second form (DRY principle), and also not to have to repeat the list of fields from `MyFormOne` (in reality there are much more then one field then in the simple example above).

How should I define `MyFormTwo`?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have to explicitly declare the entire widget, just modify the attrs which are different.
Or if you have custom widgets in the real code, I would either

1. Create a custom model field class as well which uses that widget by default, if it's a general condition, so in the form class it just works "automagically".
2. If it's just form specific (not model specific), then for that case I'd just declare the form field explicitly on Form class, not in Meta and then inheritance applies in a straightforward way.

But with default widgets (with custom attrs) I'd try something like the following

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_foo = models.CharField(_("Foo"), max_length=50)
    field_bar = models.IntegerField(_("Bar"))

class MyFormOne(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
        fields = ('field_foo', )

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFormOne, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['field_foo'].widget.attrs['size'] = 10
        # max_length should already be set automatically from model
        # TextInput is also default widget for CharField

class MyFormTwo(MyFormOne):
    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
        fields = MyFormOne.Meta.fields + ('field_foo2',)

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFormTwo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['field_foo2'].widget.attrs['size'] = 10
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will work or not (it's completely untested with Django forms/models), but if it does let me know.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_foo = models.CharField(_("Foo"), max_length=50)
    field_bar = models.IntegerField(_("Bar"))

class MyFormOne(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
        fields = ('field_foo', )
        widgets = {'field_foo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'maxlength': 50}),}

class MyFormTwo(MyFormOne):
    class Meta(MyFormOne.Meta):
        fields = MyFormOne.Meta.fields + ('field_foo2',)
        widgets = MyFormOne.Meta.widgets
        # Add new fields as a dictionary
        widgets.update({'field_foo2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'maxlength': 50}),)
        # Or add them one by one
        widgets['field_foo3'] = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'maxlength': 50})
```

Again, I have no idea if that will help you. Please let me know what results you get.

Comment: This gives `ModelForm has no model class specified.`

Comment: @surfer190 Since this answer is over 6 years old, it's possible that there are some differences in the version used to answer the question back then with the version you're currently using. Looking at the release history, the highest possible version that would have been used was Django 1.3. Can you confirm that you get the same error with version 1.3?

Comment: @surfer190 As a side note, did you add the `model = MyModel` line to the class that inherits `forms.ModelForm`? You'll want to make sure it is lowercase. You may also need to add the same line to the form that inherits from `MyFormOne`. Let me know if that solves the issue and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: It feels like the `class Meta` is not inherited. Yes, I did specify the model on class inheriting from `forms.ModelForm` but not on the classes inheriting from that form.

Comment: @surfer190 I've updated my answer. Note the parameter for MyFormTwo's Meta class. You can see information on Meta inheritance in the Django docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is a bit old, but it explains the only way I've ever been able to get form multiple inheritance to work.  It's pretty ugly.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/703/

There is also an open ticket regarding it: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7018